# Yii MANY_TO_MANY and CDbCriteria

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I'm trying to create a  CDbCriteria which will be used in a CActiveDataProvider, I need to query a value in the other side of a many to many relation.

I have the following tables:
order, user_order and user

the relations are declared correctly so I can access
$order->users[0] and see the data correctly.

I'm trying to build the following criteria:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with  = array('users');
if (isset($_SESSION['hideCard'])){
    $criteria->condition = "fname != 'Card'";
}

return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>40)
));
```

Which basically will mean that if a session variable is set I want to HIDE all the users with fname of "Card" from the DataProvider.

Any ideas on how to achieve this in a many to many relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran profiling on the queries being run, and started building my own query.

Here is the code which made it work...

```
public function searchRecent()
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with  = array('users');
        $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN user_order uo ON t.id = uo.order_id LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = uo.user_id';
        $criteria->order     = 't.id DESC';
        if (isset($_SESSION['hideCard'])){
            $criteria->join .= " LEFT JOIN loyalty_members lm ON lm.user_id = u.id";
            $criteria->addCondition("magnetic_id IS NULL");
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['hidePango'])){
            $criteria->addCondition("u.password != 'PANGO'", "AND");
        }
        $criteria->group = "t.id";
        return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>40)
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must modify your code like this:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with  = array('users'); // or just string – 'users';
if (isset($_SESSION['hideCard'])){
    $criteria->together = true; // critical fix
    $criteria->condition = "users.fname != 'Card'"; // table alias must be set to ensure filtering proper column
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['hideCard'])){
    $criteria->condition = "users.fname != 'Card'";
}
```

Or whatever the alias is for the users table, I'm only assuming its `users` from the relation name.

Comment: I tried that, and getting unknown column. I have 3 tables, order, user, and user_order, the relation is defined as 'users' in the Order object.

Comment: Can you see the SQL that is being generated for the relation, is it including the `users` table, and if so what is it called / what columns are on it.

Comment: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`business_id` AS `t0_c1`,
`t`.`service` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`discount` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`balance` AS
`t0_c4`, `t`.`open_time` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`status` AS `t0_c6`,
`t`.`call_waiter` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`decimals` AS `t0_c8`, `t`.`tstamp` AS
`t0_c9`, `t`.`station_name` AS `t0_c10`, `t`.`ext_order` AS `t0_c11`,
`t`.`waiter` AS `t0_c12`, `t`.`billnum` AS `t0_c13` FROM `order` `t`  WHERE
(users.fname != 'Card') LIMIT 40.

Comment: Are you sure that's the only SQL? It might be split over multiple statements as that isn't bringing the relations down in a single query. Is everything working as expected without this condition? Also could you clarify: You don't want any orders with those users in, or you want the orders, just don't show the user?

Answer (score 0):

CActiveDataProvider can take a model instance instead of just its class name. This allows you to preset all of your criteria in your model. Then you can use ['named scopes'](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes) in your model. e.g.

```
$model = Order::model();

if (isset($_SESSION['someCond'])) {
    $model->someNamedScope();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['otherCond'])) {
    $model->otherNamedScope();
}

return new CActiveDataProvider($model, ...)
```